# Display more google maps on jquery-mobile application

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I've a jquery-mobile application, i need to open different maps on different data-role.
My code is:

html:

```html
<!-- **    DATA-ROLE MAP-PAGE-1   ** -->  
<div data-role="page" id="map-page">
<div role="main" class="ui-content" id="map-canvas"></div></div>
<!-- **    DATA-ROLE MAP-PAGE-2   ** -->
<div data-role="page" id="map-page-2">
<div role="main" class="ui-content" id="map-canvas-2"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```css
#map-page,#map-canvas,#map-canvas-2,#map-page-2{
width: 100%;
height: 90%;
position: absolute;
}
```

js:

```js
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#map-page", function() {

var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.0983425, -118.3267434);
if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
function success(pos) {
// Location found, show map with these coordinates
drawMap(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
}
function fail(error) {
drawMap(defaultLatLng);  
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {maximumAge: 500000, enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 6000});
}
else {
drawMap(defaultLatLng);  // No geolocation support, show default map
}
function drawMap(latlng) {
var myOptions = {
zoom: 11,
center: latlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
streetViewControl: false
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
// Add an overlay to the map of current lat/lng
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latlng,
map: map,
title: "Greetings!",
animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
});

var latilongi1 = new google.maps.LatLng(40.848942, 14.250101);  

var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latilongi1,
map: map,
icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
});

}
});




$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#map-page-2", function() {

var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.0983425, -118.3267434);
if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
function success(pos) {
// Location found, show map with these coordinates
drawMap(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
}
function fail(error) {
drawMap(defaultLatLng);  
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {maximumAge: 500000, enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 6000});
}
else {
drawMap(defaultLatLng);  // No geolocation support, show default map
}
function drawMap(latlng) {
var myOptions = {
zoom: 11,
center: latlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
streetViewControl: false
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas-2"), myOptions);
// Add an overlay to the map of current lat/lng
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latlng,
map: map,
title: "Greetings!",
animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
});

             }

             });
```

The problem is that when i show first map i see it well, when i see second map it draws wrong. Some suggest to fix it?

first_map screenshot: http://i59.tinypic.com/34pc68h.png

second_map screenshot: http://i57.tinypic.com/73pls1.png

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/932NG/

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it don't works for mine purpose, i need two function for two data-role to set different markers for different maps. In this way i get the same markers on both maps.